# SQL backup error (Operating system error 5(Access is denied.))

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup

I get this error while I want to get a backup of my files ,although I must say that I connect to another persons PC with (remote desktop connection):

> Backup failed for Server '10.72.47.239\gis'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Cannot open backup device 'F:\FON_BackUp\ABPDN_DB\ABPDN_DB_backup_2022_01_19_000011_4538135.bak'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.). (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

I would very much appreciate if someone can help me out on this.

Comment: Is that a path on your local machine or relative to the server that hosts the database? If on the hosting server, does the account that is running the SQL service have permission to that directory? In powershell, you can manually check this with `get-acl -Path F:\FON_BackUp\ABPDN_DB | select -ExpandProperty access;`

Comment: hello, i hope you have a good day, yeah it have full control:  -------------------                       FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
IsInherited       : True
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : APED\ftp
IsInherited       : True
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None

Comment: I'm seeing permissions for `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` and `APED\ftp`. Does the SQL instance run under one of those two accounts?

Comment: yeah probably but I am not really sure cause I am just remote desktop controlling another PC and I am logging in as an administrator.

Comment: Take a look at `select * from sys.dm_server_services;` to find the service account under which your SQL service is running.

Comment: Hello and thanks for following up my problem. it shows these three rows: SQL Server (GIS) 2 Automatic 4 Running 3100 2022-07-12 23:21:25.6600316 +04:30 NT Service\MSSQL$GIS "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.GIS\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe" -sGIS N NULL N-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------SQL Server Agent (GIS) 2 Automatic 4 Running 9084 NULL LocalSystem "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.GIS\MSSQL\Binn\SQLAGENT.EXE" -i GIS N NULL N---------------------------------

Comment: --------------SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher (GIS) 3 Manual 4 Running 3120 NULL NT Service\MSSQLFDLauncher$GIS "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.GIS\MSSQL\Binn\fdlauncher.exe" -s MSSQL11.GIS N NULL N

Comment: Yep. It looks like you're running a named instance (i.e. `servername\GIS`) and the service is running under the default account for that instance (i.e. `NT Service\MSSQL$GIS`). Add write permissions to your backup directory for that account through Windows and you should be able to take a backup. I'd also recommend adding read permission for the same while you're there.

Answer (score 1):

Give a permissions to that file which one do you want to get a backup file

Go to file right click and go to the property and go to security and there select which server is connect that database and there give file permission and click ok

Comment: hello, I hope you have a pleasant day and thanks for answering, the problem is I already gave it all the permissions.

Comment: did you grant user "NT Service\MSSQLSERVER" with permission?